# Azure dns does not resolve

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, azure, opendns

I have started building a small application in an Azure VM. I want the VM to host a website which will be working as a portfolio. The thing is - neither the IP nor the DNS given by Azure resolve in a browser. Apache is installed and Drupal as well. How do I proceed. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a single VM or you have more VM's which will host website on it?
IF you have multiple VM's then creating Application gateway for the server will help you.

All the best :)
let me know if this work

Comment: Answers are intended to be definitive solutions.  If you need clarification, that should be done in a comment (requires a little more rep).  A helpful hint in the right direction should also go in a comment since it isn't a directly actionable solution.